# how do I create a function that randomly replaces vowels in a string with * in python

Tags: python

```
def long_string(str):
    vow_list = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

    for v in vow_list:
        new_str = str.replace(v,"*")
        return(new_str)

long_string("Why is this code not working?")
```

Comment: What do you mean, "randomly"? One at random? Each, at a certain probability? Something else? There is nothing about randomness in your sample code.

Comment: yes, i'm not sure how to add the randomness. I'd like to choose number between 0 and 4 (corresponding to 5 elements in my list a, e, i, o, u) and randomly pick a slice from the list of elements that then gets entered into my loop.

Comment: So, randomly select _one kind of a vowel_, then replace _all occurences of that vowel_? E.g. if "i" is picked randomly, `"Why *s th*s code not work*ng?"`? Please note in the future, if your question consists of just the title and some code, it is almost certainly not enough information to answer.

Comment: Randomly select a set of vowels, which could also be a set of 1, 2, 3, 5...etc vowels e.g. "a", "o", "u", from all elements in list vowel = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"] and then replace all occurrences of those vowels. Sorry my original post was not very clear. I am now to stack overflow. Will be more thorough next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered according to the comment clarification: pick a random vowel, replace all occurences of this vowel.

```
import random

text = "Why is this code not working?"
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
vowel = random.choice(vowels)
text.replace(vowel, "*")
```

`random.choice` picks a random element from a sequence. Strings are also sequences, and `"aeiou"` looks prettier (and is slightly, very slightly more memory-efficient, though this is a non-issue) than `["a","e","i","o","u"]`.

Comment: This worked Amadan. Thank you. Revised code below:

def long_string(string):
    import random
    vow_list = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
    for i in range(1,6):
        string = string.replace(random.choice(vow_list),"*")                      
    return string
long_string("Any man's death diminishes me, because I am involved in Mankind; And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; it tolls for thee.")
    "*ny man's death diminishes me, because I am inv*lved in Mankind; *nd theref*re never send t* kn*w f*r wh*m the bell t*lls; it t*lls f*r thee."

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. You are using the name `str` for a parameter, which conflicts with the name for the string type in Python.
2. You are returning the string immediately after substituting the first vowel in the list, instead of saving the string for further substitutions.

The following code works for me:

```
def long_string(string):
    vow_list = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
    for v in vow_list:
        string = string.replace(v,"*")
    return string
print(long_string("Test string"))
```

Another note: this code only handles lowercase vowels. If you want to handle uppercase as well, add `"A"`, `"E"`, `"I"`, `"O"`, and  `"U"` to `vow_list`.